# Unable to change header Content-Type to application/json

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, google-closure

Unable to change header Content-Type to application/json with Closure library. This xhr.send () is preflighted. I have made the required configurations on the serverside. But somehow from the client , I am unable to make changes to Content-Type, it always stays null. Is there any way I can force the header to change than this code ?

> xhr.headers.set('Content-Type','application/json');

```
Http-Method: OPTIONS
Content-Type: 
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], Accept-Charset=[ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3], accept-encoding=[gzip,deflate,sdch], Accept-Language=[en-US,en;q=0.8], Access-Control-Request-Headers=[origin, content-type], Access-Control-Request-Method=[POST], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[null], Host=[localhost:8181], Origin=[http://localhost], Referer=[http://localhost/?], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/12.04 Chromium/18.0.1025.168 Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19]}



Response-Code: 200
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Allow=[POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD], Date=[Wed, 11 Jul 2012 16:31:04 GMT], Content-Length=[0]}
```

Comment: An HTTP `OPTIONS` request doesn't generally have a content body and therefore doesn't usually need a content type. Are you trying to dictate the format that the *response* should be in, or are you definitely trying to set the content type of the *request*?

Comment: shouldn't you xhr.setRequestHeader("","");?

Comment: Thanks for responding. @Gareth I am trying to set the content type of request.

Comment: @the_apj I tried your way and get WARNING - Property setRequestHeader never defined on goog.net.XhrIo. I am trying XHR in initialization way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the headers should be added to the xhr.send() function in the opt_headers map:

goog.net.XhrIo.prototype.send = function(url, opt_method, opt_content, opt_headers)

- @param {string|goog.Uri} url Uri to make request to.
- @param {string=} opt_method Send method, default: GET.
- @param {string|GearsBlob=} opt_content Post data. This can be a Gears blob if the underlying HTTP request object is a Gears HTTP request.
- @param {Object|goog.structs.Map=} opt_headers Map of headers to add to the request.

So:

```
var xhr = new goog.net.XhrIol
var headers = new goog.structs.Map;
headers.set('Content-Type','application/json')
xhr.send(uri, 'OPTIONS', null, headers);
```

Something similar works fine for us...

Regards,

Rene

Comment: Thanks Rene for the pointer, I could successfully send the POST request. It was because the Server / Client network inconsistency.